# Setting PHP variable in mariadb stored-procedure; SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found

Tags: php, mysql, variables, stored-procedures, mariadb

I am currently trying to write a login/registration function for a website. When connecting to mariadb with php I would like to call a stored procedure to enter data into the db when a new user is signing up. Upon calling the procedure in php I would like to load two variables(email and password) into the procedure. The procedure should then write them(as the procedures parameters if I understand correctly) into the relating table. 
The problem of the code I have so far is, that it seems to take the variables values(which is good) and tries to find a column named like that value(which is not what I want) instead of writing those values into the relating columns(which is what I want).
So I believe, I could solve it as soon as I understand how to declare variables properly in a stored procedure in mariadb? 
(Yes, I have googled this and checked amongst others stackoverflow and the mariadb documentation but either I could not find it or it was explained in such a way that I did not understand)

I tried putting single and double quotes around the data(email, password) as well as around the VALUES(email, password). I tried INOUT instead of only IN. I tried @email as a variable definition in both test() and VALUES(). I tried changing the names of the php variables and the stored procedure parameters.

The mariadb stored procedure:

```
    DELIMITER //
    MariaDB [login_input]> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test(IN email 
    VARCHAR(150),IN password VARCHAR(255))
        -> BEGIN
        -> INSERT INTO data(email, password)
        -> VALUES (email, password);
        -> END;
        -> //
```

The mariadb table:

```
    MariaDB [login_input]> DESCRIBE data;
    +----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
    +----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | email    | varchar(150) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
    | password | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
    +----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

It is currently empty:

```
    MariaDB [login_input]> SELECT * FROM data;
    Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

The relevant php code:
pre-defined variables:

```
    $email = "test";
    $password = "test123";
```

code for connecting to the db:

```
 try {
                                //connecting to server and setting error function
                                $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=login_input", $username, $sqlpassword);
                                $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                                echo "HEY!";
                                $callingstored = "CALL test($email, $password)";
                                $conn->exec($callingstored);
                                echo "HEY!";
                        }
                        // throw error in case smth fails
                        catch(PDOException $e)
                        {
                                echo "Sorry, connection was not established." . $e->getMessage();
                        }
```

The connection is establised using PDO(if thats important).

the error I am prompted when executing the php code:
Sorry, connection was not established.SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'test' in 'field list'

Comment: Also include your PHP code, else no one going to know what is wrong except the error message you gave. From the error message, it stated that the connection was not established.

Comment: Better is to use `prepare()/execute()` ... As `"CALL test($email, $password)"` is using string concat which is bad for SQL injections.. But i believe there is not really a way to inject `CALL` but better to be safe then sorry. right? .When working with databases always always always always always always always always always always use prepared statements (`prepare()/execute()`) to prevent SQL injections **make no exceptions**.

Comment: ..  Also keep in mind if you use the [PREPARE/EXECUTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) MySQL statements in a stored procedure SQL injections are also possible unless you use the `EXECUTE ... USING ...` syntax..

Comment: @Gabriel thanks for the advice, php code is now included

Comment: @RaymondNijland thanks for the heads up, so far i am trying to prevent injection at the step of data entry in the php form already, but I will have a look into that too

Comment: *"so far i am trying to prevent injection at the step of data entry in the php form already, but I will have a look into that too "* Yes keep in mind that second order SQL injections and stored SQL injections are also possible when use the "first" stage is protected with prepared statements..

Comment: i think the best anti SQL protection is a parse tree validation meaning parsing a application query into in tree and compare it against a (generated) allowed tree... And disallow a query if even one element is added that way there is no way that a hacker/cracker can add SQL for injections.. But it is hard to make as you would need to  write a full blown (My)SQL parser atleast for the SELECT/UPDATE/DELETE parts

Comment: @RaymondNijland okay, thanks for the input you definitely lost me on the last one and its not really solving my problem but I will try to catch up with what you mentioned.

Comment: @RaymondNijland of course, I understand what you mean and indeed it is helpful. matter of fact I already put the prepare execute advice to good use but the parse tree validation I find difficult to wrap my head around for now thanks for the input again, appreciated.

Comment: Suggest using `_email` for parameter coming in.  That distinguishes it from the column named `email`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by @RaymondNijland with this comment:

Better is to use prepare()/execute() ... As "CALL test($email, $password)" is using string concat which is bad for SQL injections.. But i believe there is not really a way to inject CALL but better to be safe then sorry. right? .When working with databases always always always always always always always always always always use prepared statements (prepare()/execute()) to prevent SQL injections make no exceptions.

Thanks.